# TSQL Need assistannce - calculate number of months between dates based on the date found in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have decided to post new topic as I come across the report that require a list of clients' shipments, total revenue and now the requirements slightly changed (again), and I need to workout how many months client deal with us based on the first invoice issued / found in our database  in 2015 and 2016.
For example,

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|Client code | invoice   date            | Number of months     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|CliID 007  |                    20161001|                     1|
|CliID 012  |                    20160824|                     3|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

My current script retrieve the clients and  the invoice date but now (I am puzzled)  must work out how to  calculate a number of months between the date when the first invoice was issued in 15 and 16.

Below is the script I end up with.

```
select 
    cli.code, 
    (Select min(invoice.dfac)
     from invoice
     inner join client on client.clientid = invoice.clientid
     where client.bur = 'nlams' 
       and invoice.dfac >= '20160101' 
       and invoice.dfac <= '20161231'  
       and cli.code = client.code)
from 
    client as cli
where 
    cli.bur = 'nlams' 
group by 
    cli.Code
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Do you want to check first invoice date with current date and want number of months..?

Comment: Yes that is correct.. Thank you guys for your input

Comment: How are you defining a month?  For example. would you consider the difference between `2016/01/01` and `2016/02/28` to be the same as the difference between `2016/01/31` and `2016/02/01`?

Comment: Full month,  of course, including leap year's months to be more specific.

Comment: @piotr  In that case, would my two examples there be 1 and 0 months or 2 and 0 months respectively?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT      cli.code, MIN(invoice.dfac) firstMonth,
            DATEDIFF(month, MIN(invoice.dfac), GETDATE()) MonthsPassed
FROM        client AS cli
LEFT JOIN   invoice ON client.clientid = invoice.clientid
WHERE       client.bur = 'nlams' 
GROUP BY    cli.Code
```

Comment: Thanks Daryl, looks alright. Is any simple solution to get number of full months passed between dates?

Comment: that is as simple as it gets Piotr

Answer (score 0):

To get the number on months' difference use DATEDIFF, so your SELECT part becomes:

`Select DATEDIFF(m, MIN(invoice.dfac), GETDATE())`

Comment: There is an important distinction to be made here, as this does not actually calculate the number of months, but the number of month *boundaries* crossed.  the `datediff` between `2016/01/01` and `2016/02/28` will be the same as the difference between `2016/01/31` and `2016/02/01`

Comment: Of course, agreed. I was hoping pointing the OP at DATEDIFF would allow them to tune the output to their requirement.